# Low Cost Bitmap Rotation on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, live-wallpaper

I'm writing the code for my own live wallpaper.
The wallpaper (among other things) has a background bitmap that rotates continuously. The bitmap is big (768x768px). Every screen refresh I do:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(degrees, background.getWidth() / 2, background.getHeight() / 2);
canvas.drawBitmap(background, matrix, paint);
```

The wallpaper will run 12-18 FPS.
Is this too heavy? Are there better ways to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Kindly Accept/Up Vote answer if you have got your solution :)

Comment: Currently I'm trying your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Using `Animation`,

For Sample Example,

```
RotateAnimation animationRotator = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 10f, 10f);
animationRotator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animationRotator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // For Infinite Rotation
animationRotator.setDuration(1000); // Duration in which one rotation should get over

yourView.startAnimation(animationRotator);
```

Comment: @mneri this is what you wanted, Cheers ;)